# How to hide button drawable in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I am making a mobile app that has a responsive layout. Layout will automatically adjust depending of the screen size. When I run the app in smaller devices specifically phones with 3 inches and below screen sizes, text of the buttons are not visible and will only show button drawables. By the way, my buttons has drawableTop set above the button texts. Refer below for the screenshot before applying my code below:

[image]

This post is supposedly a question few minutes ago but then I haven't found similar post here in stackoverflow that's why I want to post it here maybe someone is also looking for a solution.

What I did was to check if the screen size is equal or lesser to 3 inches. If yes, I set the button drawables to null.

**This is the code that checks the height and width of the emulator/device:**

```
    private float dynamicFont()
      {
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
         int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
         int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
         float widthDpi = metrics.xdpi;
         float heightDpi = metrics.ydpi;
         float widthInches = widthPixels / widthDpi;
         float heightInches = heightPixels / heightDpi;
         diagonalInches = Math.sqrt((widthInches * widthInches) + (heightInches * heightInches));
         diagonalInches = (double) Math.round(diagonalInches * 10) / 10;

         return heightInches;
      }
```

**This is the code for hiding button drawables:**

```
    membershipPackagemembershipCard = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_membership_card);
    certificate = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_certificate);
    professionalDesignation = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_professional_designation);
    fromtheRegistrar = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_from_the_registrar);

    screenSize = dynamicFont();

    if(screenSize <3)
    {
        membershipPackagemembershipCard.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
        certificate.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
        professionalDesignation.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
        fromtheRegistrar.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
    }
```

The actual result is that if the app is run in a 3 inches devices or below, the drawableTop of the buttons is hidden and the texts are shown. Refer below for the actual result after applying the codes above:

[image]

Comment: See [android design guidelines for multi screensizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Comment: Please replace null to 0 like this, textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);